# "Problems and Solutions in Mathematical Finance, Volume 3: Interest Rates and Inflation Indexed Derivatives" by Eric Chin

Tags: interest-rates, mathematics

I've heard about the book "Problems and Solutions in Mathematical Finance, Volume 3: Interest Rates and Inflation Indexed Derivatives" by Eric Chin, Dian Nel, and Sverrir Olafsson. Does anyone know if this book has been released and where I might find it?

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see Volume 1 Stochastic Calculus: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119965837](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119965837), https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118845141, https://www.google.com/books/edition/Problems_and_Solutions_in_Mathematical_F/YTMxBgAAQBAJ

[image]

and I see Volume 2 Equity Derivatives: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119965829](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119965829), https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119192190, https://www.google.com/books/edition/Problems_and_Solutions_in_Mathematical_F/V3qxDQAAQBAJ

[image]

But as of March 2024, volume 3 Interest Rates and Inflation Indexed Derivatives is referenced on Google Books https://www.google.com/books/edition/Problems_and_Solutions_in_Mathematical_F/NIEWnAEACAAJ  but I can't find it available for sale. Amazon [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119965810](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119965810) says "Currently unavailable". So does AbeBooks https://www.abebooks.com/9781119965817/Problems-Solutions-Mathematical-Finance-Volume-1119965810/plp

[image]

Volume 4 Commodity and Foreign Exchange Derivatives https://www.google.com/books/edition/Problems_and_Solutions_in_Mathematical_F/ufYcnAEACAAJ Amazon says [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119965802](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119965802) "Temporarily out of stock".

[image]

I suggest you ask the authors.